# Respect user's settings for blocked steam item types

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, block, hidden

In my Android application I use the Graph API through the Android SDK.

I keep getting reports that items that were set to be hidden/blocked from the Facebook website (e.g. game posts) are still shown in my application.

The code simply queries "me/home" and process all items returned in the result.
I expected blocked entries to not be present in the result at all.
I also haven't seen any flag indicating whether an item is supposed to be hidden or not.
Looking at the privacy settings at the Facebook website also shows no app-specific settings on that matter.

Is there any way to filter items from the returned json result based to match the way items are shown on web? Is FQL better for this type of usage?

As a side note I also get reports about missing items from the news feed. Using the Graph API Explorer verifies that not all items that are shown on web are also shown in the Graph API result.

Will appreciate any hint.

Comment: This seems like a bug that should be logged with Facebook because you're right - the /me/home is filtered based on the users hidden app/user settings (which aren't available via the graph api).

Comment: sumbitted: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/302643986447511

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bug does not appear when 'Include recent activity stories' is enabled.
A workaround if you want to keep it enabled (and only if you really do because it will break your code otherwise):
add an invalid filter parameter to the query. Example: me/home? filter=garbage